# Inserting field values into database

Tags: java, mysql

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this exception: `SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).` My mysql connector version is 5.1.29. Is this possible a problem with this version, or am I not properly setting up the query?

**Scratch:**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO racebikes"
            + "(bikename, country_of_origin, cost) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?)";

    try {
        statement.setString(1, (String)winners_combo_box.getSelectedItem());
        statement.setString(2, winner_fields[0].getText());
        statement.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat(winner_fields[1].getSelectedText()));
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch(SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: create a prepared statement and then set the values

Comment: Cool name! I see what I did wrong, thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning a value to `statement` in that method, and you're using the [overload of `executeUpdate` from `Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-)... rather than the parameterless one in `PreparedStatement`.

I suspect you actually want to assign the statement using [`Connection.prepareStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO racebikes"
            + "(bikename, country_of_origin, cost) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?)";

    // TODO: Connection management?
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    try {
        statement.setString(1, (String)winners_combo_box.getSelectedItem());
        statement.setString(2, winner_fields[0].getText());
        statement.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat(winner_fields[1].getSelectedText()));
        statement.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: Don't just pretend it worked...
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be trying to reuse a statement, basically. Personally I'd try not to reuse a connection, either, using connection pooling to handle reuse of the underlying connection, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. And also, thanks for making me realize that it's important to close off my statements within the finally block. Could you explain how I could not reuse a statement?

Comment: @TheGrayFox: Well the code I've got *doesn't* reuse a statement - I've made it a local variable, so you would remove your instance variable, for example.